# Preventing mail injection in php intercepting some characters \r, \n, %0A, %0D

Tags: php, regex, email, code-injection, spam

I'd like to stop people spamming using special characters used for mail injection in php. For example `\n` and `\r` are used to concatenate several headers and so that also with `%0A` and `%0D`. So I wrote a regex to match them. But I suspect that my regex is not so efficient... something brings me to think that I'm writing something of unusable... Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is a basic example of that I'd like to do...

```
if (!preg_match('/^[^\s]./', $_POST['name']) || (preg_match('/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+|;|mime-version:|content-type:|content-transfer-encoding:|subject:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i', $_POST['name'])) || !(strpos($_POST['name'],'\r') === false) || !(strpos($_POST['name'],'\n') === false)) {
  exit("Warning: your Name contains illegal characters! This mail will not be sent!");
} elseif (!preg_match('/^[^\s]./', $_POST['subject']) || (preg_match('/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+|;|mime-version:|content-type:|content-transfer-encoding:|subject:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i', $_POST['subject'])) || !(strpos($_POST['subject'],'\r') === false) || !(strpos($_POST['subject'],'\n') === false)) {
  exit("Warning: your Subject contains illegal characters! This mail will not be sent!");
} elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*'.'@([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+))+$/', $_POST['mail'])) {
  exit("Warning: your Mail contains no valid email address! This mail will not be sent!");
} elseif (!preg_match('/^[^\s]./', $_POST['message'])) {
  exit("Warning: your Message connot be empty! This mail will not be sent!");
} else {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$mail") {
  exit("Your Mail is sent! Thanks!");
}
```

In order to match `\n`, `\r`, `%0A` and `%0D` how should I write my regex?

And

`!(strpos($_POST['subject'],'\r') === false)` `!(strpos($_POST['subject'],'\n') === false)`

are quite good?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php), is about field sanitization

Comment: I'm validating mail address using this my regex: `if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*'.'@([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+))+$/', stripslashes($_POST['fmail']))) {` thanks, I need to fix my regex in my topic, I'm not interested in `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL`.

Comment: If `stripslashes()` means that you have magic quotes enabled you have a terribly outdated server. You probably have worse problems to care about than that. In any case, sending e-mail is hard (really!) and it's normally not worth the effort of doing yourself. Just install any third-party library like Swift Mailer or PhpMailer. –

Comment: Thanks, I'm running apache 2.4 and php 5.6.17 but since I have a script that I give to other people I don't know if this people are running a modern php version or an outdated version. I put stripslashes for people that are running older version of php. Since I don't know where my script will be used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a test. The test result is a success! I tested the regex trying directly in `localhost` with different methods:

```
<?php
$test = "the dog \n was \r sleeping on the floor";
if (preg_match_all('/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+|;|mime-version:|content-type:|content-transfer-encoding:|subject:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i', $test, $tmp)) {
  echo "I found this character: '";
  print_r($tmp[1]);
  echo "'";
} else {
  echo "I cannot find any string searched";
}
?>
```

Result:

```
I found this character: 'Array ( [0] => [1] => ) '
```

Looking at source I can see the \n and the \r

```
I found this character: 'Array
(
    [0] => 

    [1] => 
)
'
```

So I think that the regex is well build.

Also other test I did with `strpos()`:

```
if !(strpos($_POST['subject'],'\n') === false)) {
```

fails with single quotes while finds the \n with double quotes...

```
if !(strpos($_POST['subject'],"\n") === false)) {
```

Conclusions: regex is well formed and `strpos()` needs "" to match \n or \r.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very thorough with regex, but I can help u by giving an alternate trick solution to your problem.

You ca use following code to solve your purpose.

```
<?php

function sanitize_strings($raw_string) {
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z_\-\\\%]+/", "", $raw_string);
}

if( $raw_string == sanitize_strings($raw_string) )
{
    echo "No illegal characters found.";
}
else
{
    echo "Illegal characters found.";
}

?>
```

Hope this works for you. :)